# d3js - multiple circles not appends by data length

Tags: d3.js

from selecting the `svg` i am adding 'g`element according to the length of datas. as well i am trying to add multiple`circles` too..

but not working. any one help me please?
here is my code :

```
var g = svg.select()
            .data(array)
            .enter()
            .append('g') //getting 2 `g` element
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(array)
            .append('circle') //no circle appended in side to `g`
            .attr("r", 2)
            .attr("cx", innerRadius)
            .attr("cy", 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `svg.select()` on anything. You need to select the element you want to append to, then `selectAll` the elements you want to append. This creates a selection to which you bind your data with the `data` function. Then you can call `enter`, and use calls like `append` to describe the behavior on enter.

You're calling `data` and `enter` before you have a selection.

Example:

```
var g = svg.select('svg').selectAll('g')
    .data(array)
  .enter().append('g')
  .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 2)
    .attr('cx', innerRadius)
    .attr('cy', 0);
```

Comment: as well do you have any idea to draw a line from center point of a arc to out side of the arc? ( i need to add a label )

Comment: You can append a `'line'` and set `x1` and `y1` to a point on the arc and `x2` and `y2` to a point outside the arc.